# Using Repeatable migration in flyway ,without duplicate insertion data in table is possible?

Tags: flyway

Im using inserting data into table using Repeatable migration  in flyway, if i already inserted 2 rows and if i need to add new row. Duplicate insertion is happening. how to avoid in repeatable migration...

Answer (score -1):

If your DB platform supports it, you could consider something like DB2's MERGE statement, or some sort of UPSERT.

But why not just make a new migration script to insert the 3rd row, and not use a repeatable migration?